# is MuPdf library faster than xpdf/poppler at rendering images from pdf pages?

Tags: performance, rendering, poppler, xpdf, mupdf

Is MuPdf library faster at rendering images from pdf pages than xpdf/poppler? They say it is high-performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I have tested mupdf is about 10% to 50% faster than poppler but that depends on pdf file of course. If you need only image rendering then mupdf is the best choice.